# @future method fired from trigger - order of execution

Tags: trigger, future

Quick introduction:

- I Approve one of many approval levels on my custom object
- the `before update` trigger is fired
- I'm searching for the approver comments but nothing's there yet (operations are not commited yet)

I would like to send the approver comments via email with `before update` or `after update` trigger (I cannot use email alert because of some complexities).

What I noticed is that when I'm trying to execute the `@future` method (from within the trigger handler class) that's searching for approver comments, it *always* works fine, I can find and send the newest comment.

As documentation states:

> Each future method is queued and executes when system resources become available.

Maybe the fact that the `@future` method always runs after the trigger is just an accident but I'm wondering if there's some sneaky logic under the hood like (i.e) the resources become available always after the trigers' cycles, and not earlier. Is there? Or can I rely on this behavior?

Comment: What is your question? The [Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) may be what you you are looking for.

Comment: The question is in the last sentence: is there some logic under the hood? The Order of Execution doesn't mention this case.